# Export people and groups from one sharepoint site to another

Tags: export

I have 5 groups with many users in Sharepoint site A.

Using SP Content Deployment Wizard tool, I exported site B and imported in site A. Though it has taken all the lists and pages successfully, it has not exported the people and groups data.

How do I export the people and groups details from one site to another site?

Answer (score 1):

To export all the user and groups using content deployment job all that needs to be done is to define that all security information should be exported in the path definition of the content deployment job. The you will get all the security information deployed too.
[image: Security information in content deployment job]